# Eliminate duplicate rows in mysql select statement

Tags: php, select, mysqli, distinct

So hoping someone can help me on this. I've read so many questions on the same issue but none answer my question. I have the following SQL SELECT statement in my PHP code:

```
$sql = "
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            pics.piclocation,
            pics.picid,
            rating 
        FROM 
            pics,
            ratings 
        WHERE 
            pics.milfid = ratings.picid 
        ORDER BY 
            ratings.rating DESC
        ";
```

However as many know the DISTINCT keyword does not eliminate duplicate rows all the time. The problem is that the same picture is getting output often more than once i.e. pics.piclocation. The idea is each pic is rated from 1 to 5 which is then inserted into the ratings table.

Any ideas on how I can produce an output and eliminate duplication piclocation rows? I want the pictures to be listed based on which picture has the most 5 ratings if that helps any.

Thanks!

Comment: What field(s) can actually be used to determine a distinct picture?

Comment: I suppose picid as that is in both the pics and ratings tables. I'm not sure to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you only want images that have a rating of `5` then go ahead and select on that, then you can count the number of 5's that image has gotten and order by that. You will also then need to group by the unique identifer for an image which looks like its `pics.milfid` and `ratings.picid`.

```
    SELECT 
        pics.piclocation,
        pics.picid,
        COUNT(ratings.rating) as nb_ratings 
    FROM 
        pics,
        ratings 
    WHERE 
        pics.milfid = ratings.picid
        AND ratings.rating = 5 
    GROUP BY 
        ratings.picid
    ORDER BY 
        nb_ratings DESC
```

If instead you just wanted the highest rated pic, then you could `SUM` the ratings:

```
    SELECT 
        pics.piclocation,
        pics.picid,
        SUM(rating) as total_rating 
    FROM 
        pics,
        ratings 
    WHERE 
        pics.milfid = ratings.picid
    GROUP BY 
        ratings.picid
    ORDER BY 
        total_rating DESC
```